# Setting up relay on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: configuration, onion-services, onion-routing, ubuntu

This is the content of `torrc` file configuration:

```
SocksPort 0
RunAsDaemon 1
ORPort 9001
ORPort [2409:4070:219c:d7f8:94cf:ac05:ee3b:b21c]:9001
ContactInfo itstrulyjenni(at)gmail(dot)com 
#DirPort 9050
IPv6Exit 0
ExitPolicy reject *:* # no exits allowed
ExitPolicy reject6 *:*
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
```

We are trying to start tor with both IPv4 and IPv6. Service is able to start. But after a few seconds I get the following error message related with ORPort/DirPort:

```
Your server (xx.xx.xx.xx:9001) has not managed to confirm that its ORPort is reachable. Relays do not publish descriptors until their ORPort and DirPort are reachable. Please check your firewalls, ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc.
```

What can be issue here? Iptables are set in Accept policy.

Comment: i am using a dynamic IP generated by my JioFi device!  Is using dynamic IP a problem?

Comment: *Is using dynamic IP a problem?* -- well... a kind of: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/9190/5234

Comment: i guess you are behind a NAT... so have you setup the correct port forwarding?

Comment: Yes, i am behind a NAT. My JioFi device has no port forwarding feature! I tried with Airtel4G wifi device and port forwarding is done. Still my ports are not reachable. Same messages:-----> Your server (xx.xx.xx.xx:9001) has not managed to confirm that its ORPort is reachable. Relays do not publish descriptors until their ORPort and DirPort are reachable. Please check your firewalls, ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you correctly opened needed Tor ports on your machine, that doesn't mean that your port is availible outside if you using a router or any device that makes you behind the [NAT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT).
Make sure you have opened them on your router and then [check if that port is opened or not](https://portchecker.co/)

Comment: After some exploration, i found that ant 4G sim based internet (Airtel, Jio) works only with IPv6. The IPv4 address they show up as part of whatismyip.com is just a psuedo ip. I tested with pings, ipv6 is reachble to ping but not IPv4 address shown up. But Tor requires IPv4 too set up a relay. What to do??

Comment: @jenni, the only thing I think might help i setting up some kind of IPv4 over IPv6 bridge, but I don't know much about it. Try to google it, I think you can find some answers there.